# ASP.Net Ajax: How to add a custom control to the asp.net 2.0 toolbox from its DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a MS AJAX toolkit DLL which I want to add to the toolbox items as a tab.

How do I go about in doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open the toolbox on the left-hand side of the IDE and find the `Ajax Controls` Tab
2. Right Click in the Tab, and select `Choose Items` (will take some time to load) (*the image shows a click on the `General` tab instead of the `Ajax Control Toolkit`*:
   [image]
   <sub>(source: [xstandard.com](http://xstandard.com/6B8EB276-820E-40B8-B681-8C6164FA5281/integration-net-toolbox-2005.gif))</sub>
3. After the `Choose Toolbox Items` window opens, click on the `.NET Framework Components` tab:

[image]
<sub>(source: [idautomation.com](https://www.idautomation.com/reporting_services/barcode_cri/Reporting_Services_Choose_Toolbox_Items.JPG))</sub>

Finally click on the `Browse...` button, and choose your DLL from there.

After that, your Control should appear in the tab.

Comment: Thanks Dreas...  But i am facing some Error there when i try to add reference to  dll which is placed on server machine.

Comment: Its Showing like "loading of dll file is failed.. Request for permission is being failed."..but when i put dll in my pc locally .it is working fine now.Controls are added to toolbox.Is this error coming because my dll was on server machine not locally

Comment: You should have a local copy of the DLL on your machine (and in your source control!)